# Splitting a file into two variables for piping to one command

Tags: pipe, curl, xargs, jq

I have a JSON object. it has two fields; `{ href: string, filename: string }`. I want to download a file from href, and set its name to `$FILENAME.pdf`. This happens in a loop

How can I do that? preferably without a loop because I always have to look up the syntax.

I'm imagining something like: `cat files.json | jq-like-splitter '.href' '.filename' | wget $HREF -o $FILENAME.pdf`

Comment: I worked out a solution, but it's not nice: `cat files.json | jq -r '.[] | "wget \(.href) -o \"\(.filename).pdf\""' > files.sh && chmod +x files.sh && ./files.sh`. I really wish I could pipe from a jq-like parser into variables without going into a loop, something like xargs.

Comment: Could you say something about why you tagged this with [tag:xargs]?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `xargs` and start a small shell script:

```
jq -r '.href, .filename' file.json | xargs -n2 sh -c 'wget "$1" -O "$2"' sh
```

Note that `wget`'s `-o` option is for the logfile and `-O` is for the "output document".

Answer (score 1):

Similar to `xargs` solution, but using `parallel`.
It think it is more elegant as it does not need a pipe and extra `sh` call.

```
parallel -n2 wget {1} -O {2} ::: "$(jq -r '.href, .filename' file.json)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a jq-splitter on Linux, but you can use sed to split the fields, reading the output into variables and then run the wget thereafter.

```
$> read HREF FILENAME < <(sed -r 's/(.*href:[ ]*)([^, ]*)(.*filename:[ ]*)([^, ]*)(.*)$/\2 \4/' files.json);wget "${HREF}" -o "${FILENAME}.pdf"
```

The `sed` uses the `-r` option to turn on regular expressions, creating capture groups to parse everything up to href, then gets its value. Then grabs everything up to filename and gets its value. printing a space separated output of capture groups 1 and 4.

The values are read into `HREF` and `FILENAME`, then a semi-colon starts a separate command to run wget with the stored values.